# How to print inkscape exported file to standard output and read from standard input

Tags: svg, png, cgi, inkscape

I would like to use inkscape generate custom Google markers for an application that I'm creating.
Since Google maps don't support SVG files directly, I'm planning to change the parameters inside the svg file then, redirect that file to Inkscape and finally print the exported png to standard output, so that a CGI script can use that for sending the results to a browser to display.

Do someone have any suggestions on how to achieve that?

Answer (score 6):

In a unix/linux environment, you can use this:

```
cat file.svg  | awk -f script.awk | inkscape --pipe --export-filename=- --export-type=png > file.png
```

---

**Note for pre-0.92 Inkscape versions:** one needed to use pseudofiles `/dev/stdin` and `/dev/stderr` to achieve this, e.g. with bash:

```
cat file.svg  | awk -f script.awk | inkscape /dev/stdin -e /dev/stderr 2> file.png
```

That was because inkscape used to send text output to `/dev/stdout` (which was a weird choice), hence you had to use `stderr` not to get your image mixed with this text.

Comment: Inkscape does seem to have options to do this more nicely nowadays: `--pipe` to read from stdin instead of from a given filename, and `--export-filename=-` (shorthand: `-e=-` to write to stdout.

Comment: Thanks @Qqwy. Have you checked whether there is no spurious output anymore to `stdout` that'd mix with the exported output?

Comment: Based on this answer and @Qqwy 's input, here's the command line to get a PNG file as output:
```cat file.svg  | awk -f script.awk | inkscape --pipe --export-filename=- --export-type=png > file.png```

Comment: @JoceNoToPutinsWarInUkraine Indeed, this works correctly now. There is no spurious output to `stdout` that would mix with the output using `--export-filename=-` any more.